# Consuming a WCF service (framework 4) from an isolated page

Tags: wcf, service

I Describe the situation:

I have a certain wcf service published in IIS7.

There is a point in my workflow in which I generate a page(.Aspx) dynamically in which, when the user enter and confirm, the service is consumed.

The problem is basically that I dont know how to do it, I have a page from which you have to consume wcf service, but that page does not belong to any Visual Studio solution, simply is hosted in IIS on the same directory as my website , which is in the solution(the website).

I can not make a service reference to the service, or I couldnt do it, then I cant use for example: "Using myService;" in my page.

Any suggestions? Is a way to consume de wcf service without adding the service reference?
Thank you!

Comment: What **binding** is your service using?? If you're using `webHttpBinding` (REST-based WCF), you might have a chance - otherwise I don't see how you could get this going without creating a full-blown WCF SOAP client-side proxy ...

Answer (score 1):

I would define a JSON endpoint in WCF as @marc_s suggests.  I would then use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make the call to the service and [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for stringifying the request.

Here is a sample HTML page that you could easily have outputted as part of your workflow (notice, no generated anything required)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>JSON Demo</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // You could set this value when you generate the HTML
        var SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:48788/JsonDemoService.svc";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#GoButton').click(function () {
                // Construct a customer object (you could pass pure JSON 
                // but I prefer to use objects and then stringify at the end)
                var customer = {
                    name: $('#Name').val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: SERVICE_URL + "/AddCustomer",
                    data: JSON.stringify(customer),
                    success: function () {
                        // Handle a successful return here
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
                        // Handle an error calling the service here                        
                        alert(thrownError);
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "html"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <input id="Name"/>
    <input id="GoButton" type="button" value="Test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see - pretty simple to send objects to the WCF service.  To complete the picture here is the service...

### Service Implementation

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Demo
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Customer
    {
        // Use the Name parameter to specify a lowercase name
        // so that it looks like Javascript on the client and
        // c# on the server
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IJsonDemoService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void AddCustomer(Customer customer);
    }

    public class JsonDemoService : IJsonDemoService
    {
        public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            // Add the customer here
        }
    }    
}
```

### .svc file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Demo.JsonDemoService" %>
```

### web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />  
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <services>
      <service name="Demo.JsonDemoService">
        <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="json"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              name="jsonEndpoint"
              contract="Demo.IJsonDemoService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The important parts at the binding configuration - it is just that which tells WCF to expect JSON.